# Creating an id number for each new node

Tags: neo4j

Each time a new member joins my application, a "member" node is create. I wanted to attach a 8 digit unique ID # to each "member" node in order to keep track of things easier. Is it possible to generate a random 8 digit number or have a number that starts at 00000001 and go up from there

// Member profile
CREATE member: MemberProfile {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    id_number: '',
}

I would like id_number to auto generate.

Comment: Might look into `node_auto_indexing` configuration option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a user ID is perhaps best done outside of neo4j, but one way to handle it would be to make a single node that would hold your current id value, then update it as part of each CREATE query. This would look something like this.

First create your MasterID node:

```
CREATE (:MasterID {id_number : 1})
```

Then, when you create a new MemberProfile node:

```
MATCH (l:MasterID)
CREATE (m:MemberProfile {first_name: '...', last_name : '...', id_number : l.id_number})
SET l.id_number = l.id_number + 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [this GraphAware Module](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) - it transparently generates a UUID for each new node (or optionally only for nodes with certain labels). You could try forking it and change UUID to your 8-digit ID, if you wish.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.